# Pathfinder: Cleric Domain Spell Slot

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric

Can I prepare a Lower leveled domain spell in a Higher leveled Domain spell slot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we combine the rules for preparing spells:

> Spell Slots
>
> The character class tables show how many spells of each level each can
>   cast per day. These openings for daily spells are called spell slots.
>   A spellcaster always has the option to fill a higher-level spell slot
>   with a lower-level spell. A spellcaster who lacks a high enough
>   ability score to cast spells that would otherwise be her due still
>   gets the slots but must fill them with spells of lower levels.

( http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Preparing-Divine-Spells )

With those for Domains:

> A cleric gains one domain spell slot for each level of cleric spell
>   she can cast, from 1st on up. Each day, a cleric can prepare one of
>   the spells from her two domains in that slot.

Then it seems there is nothing preventing you from doing it. It says you always have the option to use a lower level spell, and domain spells are prepared just like any other.